# Problem with letter "T" and unity

Tags: unity, 13.10, fonts

My unity is showing some weird characters when I type the letter "T" on it. (Image below)

Any clue ?

[image: http://imgur.com/xeBrhus]

Thanks in advance

--

Ubuntu 13.10 x64 w/ Unity
AMD fglrx 13.11beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting Unity using the instructions [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04).

Basically, just run

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

to install dconf editor if you didn't have it already, then run

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

to actually reset Unity.