# DASH does not display the letter "C"

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, unity-dash

I saw a similar reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368599/problem-with-letter-t-and-unity) but my issue is the letter "C". Up until yesterday, I did not have this issue. I have not installed any software or made hardware changes. I tried the solution from the enclosed link, but that has not resolved my issue.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, 64-bit, on an NVidia GTS 450 card. Could there have been a recent update that has caused this? I update my system daily, if there are any updates.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with GNOME here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/577592/the-letter-c-is-missing-from-gnome