# The letter 'C' is missing from GNOME

Tags: 14.04, gnome, session

Well this is an odd issue that I've come across.
I've just recently installed the GNOME shell and it's been having an issue with displaying an upper case C.

[image: Where's the C gone in Chrome?]

This also happens with notifications:
[image: No C in Caps]

The lower case c works absolutely fine. What could be the issue?
[image: The main menu works fine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the GNOME shell solved the problem. Press Alt+F2, type `r` in the box that shows up, and press enter.